# Emulate a USB downstream port

Tags: usb, host, emulator

Well, I have a USB device (kindle) with the lock/unlock button broken. The Only way to unlock the device is to connect it to a computer (not to a charger) via USB.

Is there any way to modify one usb cable to emulate the computer connection to unlocks the device been away from a computer?

Thanks

Comment: There's no easy way to modify a cable, you'd have to build a circuit that acts as a USB host device to provide the necessary communications dialogue the Kindle expects.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't work with a charger it sounds like you'd need implement a USB host as RedGrittyBrick suggested in a comment. One of the cheapest ways I can think of to get a USB host device is to use a device such as the FTDI [VNC2 - Vinculum-II Programmable USB 2.0 Host](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/VNC2.htm). They are currently under $5 in one-off quantities but will require power, a PCB, additional support circuitry and a good deal of design and programming work.

A Linux SBC (single-board computer) such as a Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone may be a more approachable option but they tend to cost more and will also require external power. It may also require some programming depending on what support the Kindle has for Linux. Personally I'd concentrate on trying to repair the broken button.